# Heroku csv file not getting recognised in settings.py

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

i am  trying to deploy my site using heroku. Being a starter just following the steps given on a website. In settings my csv and database default is not getting recognised.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', cast=Csv())

DATABASES = {
'default': dj_database_url.config(
    default=config('DATABASE_URL')
   )
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting from heroku? and at what stage of the deployment process?

Comment: @Juan cast=csv() is not recognisable, as if i have not imported the rquired library files though i have imported from decouple import config
      ALLOWED_HOSTS = config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', cast=Csv())
      NameError: name 'Csv' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Heroku; this wouldn't work locally either. The error message tells you all you need to know: you have not defined `Csv`. It's not clear what it is supposed to be, but you either need to import that function, or define it yourself.

Comment: it was supposed to come with decouple

Answer (score 0):

Install python-decouple pip `install python-decouple`
ran into the same ordeal.